# Getting value from database query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am using this code to get some data from my database in my controller

```
var NewAspNetId = from a in db.CVVersjon
                          where a.CVVersjonId.Equals(Id)
                          select a.CVVersjonId;
```

And the value I get back is

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[CVVersjonId] AS [CVVersjonId] 
FROM 
    [dbo].[CVVersjon] AS [Extent1] 
WHERE 
    [Extent1].[CVVersjonId] = @p__linq__0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the value you get back. That is the debugger showing you the query.

In order to execute the query and materialize the result, you need to enumerate `NewAspNetId`:

```
foreach (var versionId in NewAspNetId)
{
    // do something with versionId
}
```

Or, if you're sure that query returns [0..1] records:

```
var newId = NewAspNetId.FirstOrDefault();
```